# Is archival possible in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

If we implement couch db based Hyperledger fabric network, what is the possibility of data archival?

Comment: Can you explain more what is meant by *what is the possibility of data archival*?

Comment: This is not a question of a couchDB capability. There is no such feature as per my info. But in the normal application, we control the data access etc, and we can twist the logic to access another archival DB, when DB grows a bit old, by flushing old data into this so called archival DB. Here with the Blockchain concepts and a Fabric layer on top of couchDB, is such a flow/feature possible?

Comment: Just curious, is your data in the form of separate JSON-like documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Hyperledger Fabric does not support archiving or pruning of the ledger.  With the Kafka-based orderer, you can prune the Kakfa logs but not the ordering service node logs.

There is an epic in [JIRA](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-106) for this feature.  Work will likely begin after the v1.2 release (targeted for end of June).